# oracle.jbo.RowNotFoundException: JBO-25020:View row of key oracle.jbo.Key[35761] not found in Iterator

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a binding:

`setCurrentRowWithKeyValue` which points to an iterator that has a view object.
I have put a value to the binding method with  `#{row.MyTableId}`.

The `view object` in its own view object *xml* has only one *keyattribute*:

```
  <AttrArray Name="KeyAttributes">
    <Item Value="MyTableIdFk"/>
  </AttrArray>
```

When I execute the above method I get the error.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: oracle.jbo.RowNotFoundException: JBO-25020:View row of key oracle.jbo.Key[35761] not found in Iterator

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty late to answer this question,but in future it may help some one.

Check Properly how many attributes are referenced as a primary key. I also faced the same exception. My table structure was changed and number of primary key was also changed. In Entity Object, I was able to set the newly added primary key, but it was not reflecting the view Object. So I manually changed in VO. It worked.

For more reference, please follow the oracle documents for JBO errors for 25020. It may help.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26098_01/core.1112/e22506/chapter_jbo_messages.htm